# Generate a histogram of a contour with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, contour

I want to generate a histogram of a contour. I am using C++ with openCv. So far I have been able to find the contour, but I have not been able to generate the histogram, only to highlight these contours are irregular objects. I'm trying to do this to track multiple objects and identify them even after occlusions.

Code Snippet:

```
cv::Mat frameSubtracao, frameSubtracao_gray; 

cv::cvtColor(frameSubtracao.clone(), frameSubtracao_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

cv::findContours(frameSubtracao_gray.clone(), contours, hierarchy,
                 CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

Answer (score 0):

Opencv can compute the historgram for you: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html.

Also, it can peform tresholding on the values you see fit from histogram:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

Answer (score 0):

Is that contour a binary image? (That you generated from canny() function for example) if so:

you can do a **bitwise_and()** of your contour and your image, and then generate the histogram of that.

See:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html